# Disable click-prevent on injected widget

Tags: javascript, html

I am writing a Chrome extension (using html, javascript & css), that is injecting a widget into a website to display additional information. A part of this widget is a button. Unfortunately that webpage is capturing all clicks and overwrites them with custom events. The consequence is, that it is impossible, to click the button.

Is there a possibility to prevent this "click-preventing-mechanism"?

I inspected their javascript code, it seems they are catching the PointerEvents.

I would really appreciate any help.

Edit:

Here is the code for the button I'm injecting into the webpage (got it from some other page):

HTML:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="onoffswitch" class="onoffswitch-checkbox" id="myonoffswitch">
<label class="onoffswitch-label" for="myonoffswitch"></label>
```

CSS:

```
.onoffswitch {
    position: relative; width: 60px;
    -webkit-user-select:none; -moz-user-select:none; -ms-user-select: none;
}
.onoffswitch-checkbox {
    display: none;
}
.onoffswitch-label {
    display: block; overflow: hidden; cursor: pointer;
    height: 30px; padding: 0; line-height: 30px;
    border: 2px solid #999999; border-radius: 30px;
    background-color: #EEEEEE;
    transition: background-color 0.3s ease-in;
}
.onoffswitch-label:before {
    content: "";
    display: block; width: 30px; margin: 0px;
    background: #FFFFFF;
    position: absolute; top: 0; bottom: 0;
    right: 58px;
    border: 2px solid #999999; border-radius: 30px;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in 0s; 
}
.onoffswitch-checkbox:checked + .onoffswitch-label {
    background-color: #34A7C1;
}
.onoffswitch-checkbox:checked + .onoffswitch-label, .onoffswitch-checkbox:checked + .onoffswitch-label:before {
   border-color: #34A7C1;
}
.onoffswitch-checkbox:checked + .onoffswitch-label:before {
    right: 0px; 
}
```

Comment: Instead of using a Button you could use for example a `div` which is designed like a button?

Comment: And the code...

Comment: @Mazz How would that be different? Does a div behave differently than a button?

Comment: @SagarV Which code do you mean? Mine is nothing special, I can paste it but I thought it isn't necessary, please tell me if you differ. Their code is 20.000+ lines and I only have the minified version, as it is not my website, I'm writing the extension for.

Comment: Code is necessory. Please visit [How to ask a Minimal Clear Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @SagarV Alright, I edited my question with the code